# Clean up unused database tables after removing a Django app?

Tags: django

When I remove a Django app from my list of `INSTALLED_APPS`, it doesn't get rid of the old database tables; running `./manage.py makemigrations` doesn't detect any changes.

Apart from going into the database myself and dropping the old tables, is there a better way to clean up unused tables after uninstalling an app from my Django project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use migrate command by specifying a `zero` for this purpose.
Example-

```bash
$ python manage.py migrate appName zero
```

This will safely revert the database tables.

[Relevant Doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/migrations/#reversing-migrations)

After running the zero migration, you may remove the app from `INSTALLED_APPS`

Comment: Thanks! Does it also remove the stuff from django_content_type, auth_permission, and so on?

Comment: [`manage.py remove_stale_contenttypes`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#remove-stale-contenttypes) should clean up the content types - the auth permissions don't appear to have a parallel command.

Comment: An even better command: `./manage.py remove_stale_contenttypes --include-stale-apps`. Especially if you run this after you already deleted the installed apps :)

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
./manage.py migrate --run-syncdb
```

It automatically deletes the tables concerning the app you removed. Take note that if you have already made manual changes to the database, you have to back them up before running this command.

**Another option** is to use the " inspectdb "command.

1. First remove the app from your "INSTALLED_APPS"
2. Then run `./manage.py inspectdb > models.py`
3. Remove the models in the generated models.py file that belong to the app you just uninstalled.
4. Run `./manage.py migrate --fake`